# Eloquent relationships not working on query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have these 2 models where im trying to implement eloquent relationships

Activities model

```
    protected $connection = 'mysql_dinamica';
    public $table = "pqr_activities";
    protected $fillable = [
        'service', 'pqrid','noefectiva_direccionerrada', 'noefectiva_luminariaprivada',
        'noefectiva_noexisteluminaria', 'noefectiva_quejasolucionada', 'noefectiva_luminariasinrecibir',
        'noefectiva_noexisteposte', 'noefectiva_luminariarobada', 'suspension_requierepoda',
        'suspension_imposibilidadtecnica', 'suspension_postemalestado', 'suspension_dificilacceso',
        'suspension_zonaaltoriesgo', 'suspension_abejas', 'accionsuspension',
        'validacion_personal', 'validacion_telefonica', 'validacion_tecnico',
        'validacion_fallida', 'contactovalidacion', 'telefonovalidacion',
        'fechavalidacion', 'observacionvalidacion', 'fusibleinstalado',
        'fusiblecantidad', 'conectorinstalado', 'conectorcantidad',
        'soportewattios', 'soportecantidad', 'bombillodesmontado',
        'bombilloinstalado', 'bombillowattios', 'bombillocantidad',
        'fotoceldadesmontado', 'fotoceldainstalado', 'fotoceldacantidad',
        'arrancadordesmontado', 'arrancadorinstalado', 'arrancadorcantidad',
        'balastodesmontado', 'balastoinstalado', 'balastocantidad',
        'basefotoceldadesmontado', 'basefotoceldainstalado', 'basefotoceldacantidad',
        'cableinstalado', 'cablecantidad', 'trazabilidadmaterial', 'ajuste_bombillo',
        'ajuste_fotocelda', 'ajuste_basefotocelda', 'reconexion_luminaria',
        'reparacion_conexionesinternas', 'limpieza_internaluminaria',
        'despeje_flujoluminoso', 'desmonte_taller', 'trabajo_redes',
        'reconexion_circuito', 'desmonte_poste', 'instalacion_bombillo',
        'instalacion_fotocelda', 'instalacion_basefotocelda', 'instalacion_conector',
        'instalacion_balasto', 'instalacion_arrancador', 'instalacion_soporte',
        'instalacion_condenso', 'instalacion_luminaria', 'cambio_transformador',
        'instalacion_poste', 'cambio_bombillo', 'cambio_fotocelda',
        'cambio_basefotocelda', 'cambio_conector', 'cambio_balasto',
        'cambio_arrancador', 'cambio_soporte', 'cambio_condenso',
        'cambio_posicionluminaria', 'instalacion_transformador',
        'cambio_poste', 'created_at', 'updated_at'
    ];
    protected $primaryKey = 'service';

    public function pqrs()
     {
      return $this->hasMany('App\PqrGeoreference');
     }
```

PqrGeoreference model

```
    protected $connection = 'mysql_dinamica';
    public $table = "pqr";
    protected $fillable = [
        'id', 'provincia', 'canal', 'registro', 'servicio', 'tiposervicio', 
        'barrio','direccion', 'conca', 'coordenadas', 'latitud', 'longitud', 'luminaria', 'potencia', 'observacion',
        'codigousuario', 'usuario', 'tipodedocumento', 'rutadeldocumento', 'tipousuario', 'telefonofijo', 'celular1',
        'celular2', 'correoelectronico', 'direccioncorrespondencia', 'fecharadicacion', 'horashastaaprobacion',
        'diashastaaprobacion', 'fechapqr', 'mespqr', 'mesletraspqr', 'estadopqr', 'trazabilidad', 'fechaasignacioncuadrilla',
        'fechadesuspension', 'horashastasuspension', 'fechareactivacion', 'fechacierrecampo', 'horashastacierrecampo',
        'horastotalsolucionpqr', 'fechacierresistema', 'postetiposervicio', 'iddiariocuadrilla', 'codigoconductor', 'prioridad',
        'conductor', 'codigoliniero', 'liniero', 'fechaturno', 'turno', 'placavehiculo', 'created_at', 'updated_at'
    ];
    public $primaryKey = 'id';

    public function activities()
     {
       return $this->belongsTo('App\Activities', 'pqrid');
     }
```

What I'm trying to do is, joining my pqr table and activities so I can see ALL the information of both tables on the related queries, some might not have an activity asigned yet.

Now this is the query where I'm trying to retrieve the data, it is a collection from Maatwebsite Laravel Excel

```
    public function collection()
    {
      $datab = PqrGeoreference::with('activities')
             ->whereBetween('pqrdate', [$this->startD, $this->endD])
             ->get();
      return $datab;
    }
```

It returns all pqr's in a period of time, but not the activities asigned to them.

Comment: Can you add table definitions of above models

Comment: There is no column named as `pqrid` defined in `PqrGeoreference` how these 2 models are related?

Comment: I think your relationships are backwards - Activities `belongsTo` PqrGeoreference, and PqrGeoreference `hasMany` Activities

Comment: Thanks for answering, if i reverse the relationship, it remains the same, only pqr table returned.